# RSync incremental backups, backing files that haven't changed. Does file access time cause a re-backup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, backup, rsync

I backup my LAMP server using RSync over SSH.

Currently, it's on an hourly incremental schedule.

From a 14GB full backup, it's backing up a further 15~MB hourly.

Looking at the files it's backing up again, I think most of these haven't changed.

Does the file last accessed time attribute mean the file has technically changed and would be re-backed up?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the full rsync command you are using.

Comment: you might want to check out rdiff-backup instead

Answer (score 1):

No, rsync does not check the access time (atime) of a file. Instead, it use the modified and changed times (ctime/mtime) to check if a file changed.

What you should pay attention, however, is that rsync is preserving mtime (-t option) in the fist place. If not, any further attempt will re-sync the same files.

`rsync -a` includes '-rlptgoD' options, so if you use '-a' it will be sufficient.